# JTextField, removing end characters

Tags: java, string, jtextfield

Is there an inbuilt function that can remove the last character from a `JTextField`, or is the only way to set the string to a new string with the last character removed?

```
JTextField textfield = new JTextField(sometext);

// What I'm looking for
textfield.removeLastCharacter();

// What I'm using
char[] text = textfield.getText().toCharArray();
String string = "";
for (int i = 0; i < text.length - 1; i++) string += text[i];
textfield.setText(string);
```

Comment: _I am trying to get a 'back' feature_ don't understand why/what exactly you are trying to do: on clicking the button remove a) the last input b) the last char c) the last char if it is a digit d) .. Please clarify, the answer depends on your _exact_ requirements, your job to describe it completely :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make:

```
textField.setText(""+textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText ().length - 1);
```

Comment: Upvoted but using '""+' is an ugly hack especially when the right hand of the + returns a String anyway.

Comment: where you see ' ' ? 


yeah i forgot it returns a string anyway ^^ but those 2 bytes.. :D

Answer (score 4):

```
Document doc = textField.getDocument();
doc.remove(...);
```

You will also need to get the length of the Document so you know which character to remove. Check out the Document API for the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

Do this. it works for java programs. 
Use your **Textfield's name** for **`textField`**

```
textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText ().length() - 1));
```